# Will another peer be responsible for anchor peer's functionality

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

in a fabric network, org A has two peers, one is anchor peer if this anchor peer is down, would another peer be responsible for anchor peer's functionality?
eg, invoking the request or query for SDK?
And in the group peers of an org, how to assign the role of every peer, and where to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor peer(s) are the mechanism used by gossip to bootstrap gossip communication between organizations.  If you aren't using gossip (which is required for things such as service discovery and private data), anchor peers really don't matter.

In terms of being able to handle invoke and queries, any peer in an organization can be used provided the peer has joined the appropriate channels and has the required chaincode installed.

To ensure that an organization's endorser(s) are highly available, it is recommended that you set up at least 2 peers and configure them exactly the same.

Comment: Too many thanks! I wonder that how to recognize the peer is down, and then perform the query on another peer in client?

Comment: This may be useful: the service discovery feature added in 1.3: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/discovery-overview.html